# firestore getDocuments().size() != getDocumentChanges().size()

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I query my firestore db with a complex query

```
            .whereIn(gender_node, getInterestedIn())
            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(birthdate_year_node, getShowAgeMax() + 1)
            .whereLessThanOrEqualTo(birthdate_year_node, getShowAgeMin())
```

but I run into an `IndexOutOfBoundException`, because `getDocuments().size()` is not equal to  `getDocumentChanges().size()`.

I can't find anything in the documentation, does anybody know when or why `getDocuments().size()` != `getDocumentChanges().size()` ?
I assumed there would be a `DocumentChange` for every `Document`.

It doesn't happen every time, which makes it hard to debug.

There are 7 test documents and `getDocuments().size()` is always 7, but `getDocumentChanges().size()` is sometimes 5. Always seems to be the number 5, as far as I have seen.

Comment: The closing parenthesis in that last line don't seem correct. Should probably be `.whereLessThanOrEqualTo(birthdate_year_node, getShowAgeMin())`.

Comment: Have you tried Frank van Puffelen's recommendation? If you remove that parenthesis, does it work?

Comment: Oh no, I simplified the source code a bit and that extra parathesis was my doing. If there was a parathesis too much, the IDE would have shown it as a syntax error.

Comment: Could you please share the code where you have mentioned getDocuments().size() != getDocumentChanges().size()?

Comment: That's nowhere in the code, I saw it in the debugger. It's true anywhere in `onEvent` of the  `SnapshotListener` `EventListener<QuerySnapshot>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getDocument().size() and getDocumentChanges().size() are two different methods.

1. The getDocumentChange().size() returns the list of documents that
   changed since the last snapshot.
2. The getDocument().size() returns
   the list of documents.

The details about these methods can be found out in the [documentation section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot).

Suppose, if you have 7 documents and there are changes on 2 documents since last snapshot, then getDocument().size() would be 7( including the newly added or modified documents) [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentChange#public-querydocumentsnapshot-getdocument) and getDocumentChanges().size() would always refer to the number of changed documents, which in this case is 2.
And hence is the condition,

> getDocument().size() ! =  getDocumentChanges().size()

true.

Comment: Ok, so do I get it right: If I send a query, the query returns all the documents in `getDocuments()` and all document changes in `getDocumentChanges()` and if there is no change in a document then `getDocument().size() ! = getDocumentChanges().size()`?

Is there any way to tell firestore to only send documents which have changed? To minimize traffic?

Comment: Yes, getDocument() returns all the documents in this QuerySnapshot as a List in order of the query; and getDocumentChanges() returns the list of documents that changed since the last snapshot.

Comment: And, Firestore queries don't have a notion of querying "only things that have changed". You will need to create that notion on your own. The usual way to do this is by recording a timestamp in each document with the time it was last updated, then using that field in a range filter to get only documents updated since the latest update was received. You will need to track that latest update timestamp in the client. One possibility is to use the greatest timestamp seen in any document to date.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have an extra paranthese closed in this line? (just after `birthdate_year_node`)

```
.whereLessThanOrEqualTo(birthdate_year_node),getShowAgeMin())
```

Otherwise, can you run your code with each one of the 3 "where" clauses seperately so we know which one of the three is creating the issue.

Comment: Oh no, I simplified the source code a bit and that extra parathesis was my doing. If there was a parathesis too much, the IDE would have shown it as a syntax error.

Comment: The problem is, the bug doesn't appear every time. I can run them all seperately, but most likely they al work seperatly and then they work all together, like 90% of the time. There are 7 test documents and `getDocuments().size()` is always 7, but `getDocumentChanges().size()`is sometimes 5. Always seems to be the number 5, as far as I have seen.